# Onclick add border bottom using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created the project In which I am using **jQuery**. In which nav is present. When I click to this nav then it displayed content. Now, **I am trying to add this clickable nav to border-bottom effect using add CSS or class method.** And First, nav is default clicked.

Below I am displaying my JQuery Code:

```
 $('.nav-collapse a').click(function () {
        $('.bb-wizard-page ').hide();
        $(this.getAttribute('datahref')).show()
    });
```

Comment: is `datahref` a data attribute on the `a` element? if so and you're using jQuery to get that data attribute value you can use `$(this).data('href')`, store that in a variable and us it in the selector. i'll write an actual example if `datahref` is a data attribute and this applies. if you're trying to just use the `href` attribute then I will adjust the answer

Comment: When I'm using hef then #TabName displayed in URL, which is not necessary for me. That's why I am using this datahref

Comment: what does `this.getAttribute('datahref')` return?

Comment: It nothing return anything in url, only show content of this ab.

Comment: that is what I mean. if you were to `console.log(this.getAttribute('datahref'))` what would it show?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196757/discussion-between-pritesh-and-michael-cacciano).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you are looking to add border-bottom to the nav item you've selected.

I've added 2 lines before and after your existing code.

`$this` just a quick cache for the jQuery selector for the link that was clicked.

`$menuLinks` traverses from the clicked link up to the its parent (the menu bar) and then finds all the children links

```
$('.nav-collapse a').click(function () {
    const $this = $(this);
    const $menuLinks = $this.parent().find(".nav-link");

    $('.bb-wizard-page ').hide();
    $(this.getAttribute('datahref')).show();

    // Remove 'selected' class from links
    $menuLinks.removeClass("selected");
    // Adds 'selected' class to clicked link
    $this.addClass("selected");

});
```

From there, you can create a css class for `.nav-link.selected` with the style you need.

Comment: It works Nice, But  I need the First tab selected by default and code of first tab id below :

Comment: `<div class="nav-collapse"
                                                                style="width:61%;text-align: right;">
                                                                <a class="nav-link" onclick="$('#last').hide();"
                                                                    datahref="#Home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a> </div>`

Comment: Depending on how your HTML is generated, you could either just add the `selected` class to the first a.nav-link manually and if you're unable to add it when the page is generated, you can always add the class manually after the page loads.